# how use require_one views in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, view, require-once

i am beginner in cakephp and i want use file with `percalname.php` in my view.
this file have this path :
`app\webroot\files\percalname.php`
and i write this code in my view (this code is in line 17)

```
require_once $this->webroot.'../files/percalname.php';
```

but i face this message :

> require_once(/cake/../files/percalname.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\views\orders\add.ctp, line 17]

Comment: Is that a valid path? Do you actually have a /files top-level directory on your system? I think you'll find your solution if you carefully consider that `$this->webroot` is set to `/cake/`, and then work your way from there. Is there a different variable you have access to which statically points to app\webroot ?

Comment: The function [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) can be useful debugging things like this.  Just do a die(realpath($path)); and see if it's valid or you are too deep/shallow.

Comment: if your php file contains some classes, then you must use it as a vendor library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `vondor` .
first you should copy file to vendor folder and use `app::import()` like this link.
[vendor example in cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/944/Vendor-examples)

good luck.